# what is the probability of bin 1 was chosen

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

Bin 1 contains 20 parts, 5 are defective. Bin 2 contains 15 parts, 4 are defective. One of these Two Bins is chosen at random and 3 parts are randomly selected from the bin chosen. if 2 of the 3 parts are defective. what is the probability that Bin 1 was chosen?

Since the sample space is small and it is without replacement. I used the Hypergeometric to calculate the probability of having 2 out of 3 defective.

for Bin 1 $\frac{\binom{5}{2}\binom{15}{1}}{\binom{20}{3}} = 0.145$

for Bin 2 $\frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{11}{1}}{\binom{15}{3}} = 0.1315$

Now to find back the probability of which Bin was chosen I can't find away other than multiplying the result of probability of chosen 2 out 3 by the probability of chosen one Bin out of 2. which it is $0.145 * 0.5 = 0.7252$

The book result is $0.476$

Comment: Check https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Statement_of_theorem

Comment: I don't see any link between them. assuming that $P(A|B)$  is the probability Bin 1 knowing the probability of 2 out of three and same for $P(B|A)$ . still missing part of the story

Comment: Think more, there is nothing missing, except you have swapped the probabilities for the bins. Your book answer is correct and is better recognised perhaps as $\approx 0.1315/(0.1315+0.145)$.

Comment: Should I see it like this. $\frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(B)}$. $P(A \cap B)$ means the probability of having 2 out of 3 defective and Bin2. while $P(B)$ is the probability of having 2 out of 3 defective for both Bins. and $P(A|B)$ is probability of choosing Bin 2 knowing the probability of 2 out of 3 defective. I'd like to see your interpretation plz

Comment: I'd like to hear from you whenever you can. I can't see the $.1315$ joint probability but conditional probability $P(B|A)$. one more why $P(B)$ the probability of having 2 out of 3 defective have to add the result of both Bins assuming it is the full space. thanks

Comment: Have answered in more detail below.  You should be able to figure out any gaps remaining...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_1$ be the event that bin 1 is chosen and $A_2$ be the event that bin 2 is chosen. Let $B$ be the event that the outcome is $2$ defective parts out of $3$ selected.  We want to find $P(A_1 | B)$.

By Bayes formula, this is 
$$P(A_1 | B) = \frac{P(B | A_1) P(A_1)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(B|A_1)P(A_1)}{P(B|A_1)P(A_1)+P(B|A_2)P(A_2)}=\frac{P(B|A_1)}{P(B|A_1)+P(B|A_2)}$$
where the last simplification is because $P(A_1)=P(A_2)=\frac12$.

You already have these terms (though you have swapped the final numbers), for e.g.
$$P(B | A_1) = \frac{\binom{15}1\binom52}{\binom{20}3} =\frac5{38} \approx 0.13158$$

Comment: thanks, it is very clear now, just last thing to know why the term $P(B)$ considered as the domain between the two Bins

Comment: it helped a lot thanks again